# How to publish two different bib files in CV

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I have two separate bib files. One for journals and other for conference publications. Now I want to publish both of them in the CV. Any idea how to do it?

```
\renewcommand{\refname}{Journal Publications}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{MMjournals} 
\renewcommand{\refname}{Conference Publications}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{MMconference}
```

The problem with above code is, it is publishing the MMjournals twice. It did not publish the conference proceedgins. How to fix it?

Comment: I'd suggest you switch to biblatex and use the type feature of the \printbibliography command.

Comment: @nhck Thanks. Can you provide a link on how actually use that command.